# Alter ENUM column and add value to that column in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, enums, eloquent, database-migration

I have a **MySQL** database with a table called user_level_attempt. That table has a **ENUM** type column with **['PROGRESSED', 'STOPPED', 'COMPLETED']** values. I need to write a migration to add another value (let's say 'PASSED') to that column. After adding, it'll look like this, **['PROGRESSED', 'STOPPED', 'COMPLETED', 'PASSED]**. How can I do that in Laravel? 
I tried the following solution but it doesn't seem like a good practice/solution.

```
 /**
         * Schema table name to migrate
         * @var string
         */
        public $set_schema_table = 'bt_user_level_attempt';


        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::table($this->set_schema_table, function ($table) {
                $table->dropColumn('status');
            });

            Schema::table($this->set_schema_table, function ($table) {
                $table->enum('status', ['PROGRESS', 'STOPPED', 'COMPLETED', 'PASSED'])->default('PROGRESS')->after('effective_time_spend');
            });
        }

/**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table($this->set_schema_table, function ($table) {
            $table->dropColumn('status');
        });

        Schema::table($this->set_schema_table, function ($table) {
            $table->enum('status', ['PROGRESS', 'STOPPED', 'COMPLETED'])->default('PROGRESS')->after('effective_time_spend');
        });
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try with `DB::statement` method:

Use the `DB::statement` method:

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE ".$this->set_schema_table." CHANGE COLUMN status ENUM('PROGRESS', 'STOPPED', 'COMPLETED','PASSED') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PROGRESS'");
```

Comment: CHANGE is not working. Instead of CHANGE, I tried MODIFY and it worked!

Comment: you can do the same to my complete solution as well ;)

Answer (score 8):

After all, I figure out to find a solution. Thanks to all fellows for enlightening me. :)

```
/**
     * Schema table name to migrate
     * @var string
     */
    public $set_schema_table = 'bt_user_level_attempt';


    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE ".$this->set_schema_table." MODIFY COLUMN status ENUM('PROGRESS', 'STOPPED', 'COMPLETED', 'PASSED') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PROGRESS'");
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE ".$this->set_schema_table." MODIFY COLUMN status ENUM('PROGRESS', 'STOPPED', 'COMPLETED') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PROGRESS'");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to documentation:

> Only the following column types can be "changed": bigInteger, binary, boolean, date, dateTime, dateTimeTz, decimal, integer, json, longText, mediumText, smallInteger, string, text, time, unsignedBigInteger, unsignedInteger and unsignedSmallInteger.

So the ENUM cannot be modified using simple migration syntax. But you can migrate your column using a custom statement:

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE ".$this->set_schema_table." MODIFY COLUMN status ENUM('PROGRESS', 'STOPPED', 'COMPLETED','PASSED') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PROGRESS'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your migration file before the schema.

```
public function __construct()
    {
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::getDoctrineSchemaManager()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

try something like :

**edit**

```
$table->enum('converted', array('yes','no'))->default('no');
```

Comment: This creates/modifies column of VARCHAR type (with CHECK constraint), not ENUM type.